# Reducing template parameter with using or typedef

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, typedef, using

I'm trying to increase my code readabiliy by introducing the "`using`" keyword.

```
namespace EigenRM
{
    template<typename T>
    using MatrixX<T> = Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>;
}
```

This code is not working.
I've seen examples using "`using`" to remove all template parameters but none for retaining one. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the `<T>` after `MatrixX`

```
template<typename T>
using MatrixX<T> = Eigen::Matrix<T, ...
// wrong ....^^^
```

If you precede the `using` definition of a name `foo` with a template declaration, it's implicit that you're defining the template argument over `foo`, so simply

```
namespace EigenRM
{
    template<typename T>
    using MatrixX = Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>;
}
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP says

> This is exactly what i am not trying to do. I am trying to write `EigenRM::MatrixX<double>` //instead of `Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>` within an untemplated function

This is exactly what you get if you remove the "`<T>`": `EigenRM::MatrixX<double>` become an alias for `Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>`.

I'm without an `Eigen` installation but the following example should explain what I mean

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename, typename, typename>
struct foo;

template <typename T>
using bar = foo<T, float, int>;

int main ()
 {
   static_assert(std::is_same< bar<double>,
                               foo<double, float, int> >{}, "!");
 }
```

Comment: This is exactly what i am not trying to do.
I am trying to write 
    EigenRM::MatrixX<double> //instead of
    Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>
within an untemplated function

Comment: @coJetty - answer improved: hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, i get it now. Thanks a lot.